# On the convergence of a two-sided series

Tags: sequences-and-series, proof-verification, absolute-convergence

### Background

Let $\left\{ {{a_n}} \right\}_{ - \infty }^\infty $ be a two sided sequence (is there a more proper term?) of complex numbers.

As far as I know (please correct me if I am wrong) we say that $$\sum\limits_{n =  - \infty }^\infty  {{a_n}} $$ converges if and only if the following two series converge:
$$\sum\limits_{n =  - \infty }^{ - 1} {{a_n}} ,\sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {{a_n}} $$

We know that the existence of $\mathop {\lim }\limits_{N \to \infty } \sum\limits_{n =  - N}^N {{a_n}} $ does not imply the convergence of $\sum\limits_{n =  - \infty }^\infty  {{a_n}} $

since for example $\mathop {\lim }\limits_{N \to \infty } \sum\limits_{n =  - N}^N n $ exists and the limit is zero (it is in fact the zero sequence, which limit is also zero) but the series $\sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  n $ does not converge, therefore $\sum\limits_{n =  - \infty }^\infty  {{a_n}} $ diverges.

**My question is the following:**

(1) Let's say $\mathop {\lim }\limits_{N \to \infty } \sum\limits_{n =  - N}^N {\left| {{a_n}} \right|} $ exists. Does that imply that $\sum\limits_{n =  - \infty }^\infty  {{a_n}} $ converges? converges absolutely?
I think so and I'll try to prove it.

**My attempt:**

Let $\varepsilon  > 0$.
Since the limit $\mathop {\lim }\limits_{N \to \infty } \sum\limits_{n =  - N}^N {\left| {{a_n}} \right|} $ exists, by the Cauchy criterion we have a natural number ${N_0} $ such that for all $N > {N_0}$ and for all natural $p$ the following takes hold:
$\sum\limits_{n =  - N + p}^{N + p} {\left| {{a_n}} \right|}  - \sum\limits_{n =  - N}^N {\left| {{a_n}} \right|}  = \sum\limits_{ - \left( {N + p} \right)}^{ - \left( {N + 1} \right)} {\left| {{a_n}} \right|}  + \sum\limits_{N + 1}^{N + p} {\left| {{a_n}} \right|}  < \varepsilon $

But that implies

**(1)** $\sum\limits_{N + 1}^{N + p} {\left| {{a_n}} \right|}  < \varepsilon $
so by Cauchy's criterion the series $\sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {{a_n}} $ converges absolutely.

**(2)** $\sum\limits_{-(N + p)}^{-(N + 1)} {\left| {{a_n}} \right|}  < \varepsilon $
so by Cauchy's criterion the series $\sum\limits_{n = -\infty}^{-1}  {{a_n}} $ converges absolutely.

Thus $\sum\limits_{n =  - \infty }^\infty  {{a_n}} $ converge absolutely and therefore converges.

Am I correct?

Comment: Your proof is fine but I suggest using an upper bound instead of Cauchy property. $\lim \sum_{-N}^{N}|a_n|$ exists iff there is a finite constant $M$ such that $\sum_{-N}^{N}|a_n| \leq M$ for all $n$ and the rest should be clear from this.

Comment: Thanks, great suggestion!